# How do I hide this paragraph tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm quite new to all this but I learned quite quickly, as it's really easy in my opinion. I'm trying to make a button hide a `<p>` tag that another button spawned. How can make the button (At the bottom of code) make the `<p>` tag disappear?

```html
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('date_button').innerHTML = Date()">
Click this button to display the current time!</button><br>
<p id="date_button"></p><br><br>
<button onclick="myFuction()">Click this to hide date.</button>
```

Comment: Instead of apologizing for messy code, maybe just clean it up :). It'll help you understand your own code better as well

Comment: `<script>function myFunction(){ document.getElementById("date_button").style.display = "none"; }</script>`

Comment: Most of what you need to teach yourself the answers to such questions can be found on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn

Comment: Your downvotes are probably coming from your question not demonstrating that, before asking, you 1) did adequate research on possible solutions and 2)  attempted to code a solution yourself (which you reasonably thought should work but didn't). Demonstrating such an attempt is best done by including what's referred to as a "minimal, complete, verifiable example." See more info at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the called function and using display:none hide the paragraph

```js
function myFuction() {
  document.getElementById('date_button').style.display = 'none'
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('date_button').innerHTML = Date();document.getElementById('date_button').style.display='block'">
Click this button to display the current time!</button><br>
<p id="date_button"></p><br><br>
<button onclick="myFuction()">Click this to hide date.</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, kinda. Now I can't press the button to show the date again unless I reload the page.

Comment: You also want to set the display back to 'block' when you press the Show button again.

`document.getElementById('date_button').style.display='block'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think this can help

```
function myFuction() {
    document.getElementById('date_button').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: **onclick="myFuction()"**

Comment: Good catch... :D

Answer (score 0):

In your case you want to show it again so you need to set its `innerHTML` to `''`. In your case if you will do `style.display = 'none'`. It will not show `<p>` again

```js
function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById('date_button').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('date_button').innerHTML = Date()">
Click this button to display the current time!</button><br>
<p id="date_button"></p><br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click this to hide date.</button>
```

Comment: You also could set the display back to 'block' when you press the first button again. 

`document.getElementById('date_button').style.display='block'`

Comment: @Sid Jonnala yes you can also use that but here my method is also working